# Cast object in ArrayList extension doesn't see it's methods

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

So I have this interesting problem...
I want to access methods of the object which is retrieved from List with is extended by ArrayList.

It looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class PropertyList<Property> extends ArrayList {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7854888805136619636L;

    PropertyList(){
        super();
    }

    PropertyList(Collection<Property> c){
        super(c);
    }

    boolean containsProperty(PropertyList<Property> pl){
        Property asdf = (Property) this.get(4);
        System.out.println(asdf.<can't access "Property" methods>);  //mark
        return false;
    }

}
```

Any idea why I can't access methods in marked line?
To clarify - methods in Property object are public.

EDIT:
Property description:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Property {

@XmlValue
private String property = null;

@XmlAttribute
String state;
@XmlAttribute
String name;
@XmlAttribute
String type;
@XmlAttribute
String value;

Property(){}

Property(String state, String name, String type, String value){
    this.state = state;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

@Override 
public String toString(){
    return state + " " + name + " " + type + " " + value;
}

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `extends ArrayList<Property>` ? regardless, can't you show the code for `Property` as well?

Comment: @Shark Indeed. As it stands now it makes no sense. However, the explicit cast to `Property` makes me want to see the definition too :)

Comment: In any case, shouldn't your class declaration go like this: `public class PropertyList<T> extends ArrayList<T>` and you can easily hardcode the `T` to `Property` ?

Comment: @jensgram yeah, but the cast does make me wonder why `asdf` can't access it's methods as well.

Comment: @Shark Exactly.

Comment: @OP ok so the only two methods that should be accessible to you are `getName()` and you should be able to test your `toString` implicitly by printing the object in the `System.out.println("toString() test: "+asdf);` if it prints `state + " " + name + " " + type + " " + value` it should be ok and everything is working fine.

Comment: You're not casting to the class Property. You're casting to the generic type of your PropertyList class, that you chose to name Property instead of T or E or whatever other conventional single letter, and which thus shadows the Property class. You should almost never extend collection classes. And certainly not in this case.

Comment: yeah, toString works implicitly

Comment: ok, then try declaring as what I said (using generic  types) as what @JBNizet pointed out is right, it's being shadowed. (I guess `Property` works like a generic type in this case, similar to `T` or `E` or `GenericType` which could be anything) instead of your concrete `Property` class.

Comment: @Shark You have the correct answer. A further hint to it is that the `Property` class is not `import`ed. OP should use `public class PropertyList extends ArrayList<Property> {` instead of `public class PropertyList<Property> extends ArrayList {` Can you consider making it a fully-fledged answer?

Comment: @SylvainBoisse thanks, and thanks for the nudge to promote the comment into a full-fledged answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor your code to explicitly refer to your `Property` class instead of using it as a generic-type similar to `E`, `T` or any other `GenericType`. The problem in your case is that `Property` is inferred to `GenericType` and is not referencing your concrete `Property` class but is rather shadowing it - making it the same as if you used

```
public class PropertyList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
```

So, something along these lines:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class PropertyList extends ArrayList<Property> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7854888805136619636L;

    PropertyList(){
        super();
    }

    PropertyList(Collection<Property> c){
        super(c);
    }

    boolean containsProperty(PropertyList<Property> pl){
        Property asdf = (Property) this.get(4);
        System.out.println(asdf.<can't access "Property" methods>);  //mark
        return false;
    }

}
```

You'll know it works "fine" since your IDE will bug you to import the `Property` class.

If you don't want to limit it to just your `Property` class, use

```
PropertyList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
```

but then you'll get the exact same behaviour as you have now - meaning no method lookups/availability since `T` can be anything, and is (i think) defaulted/infered to Object.

Doing it the first way should show you the `getName()` method in the marked line.

The real problem solver is this:

```
PropertyList<T extends Property> extends ArrayList<T>
```

which actually uses a generic-type `T` which extends your `Property` class instead of shadowing it like in your initial solution/attempt.

Comment: Good answer. If I may, for the latter part, the Generic `T` can be restricted to Property like so: `PropertyList<T extends Property> extends ArrayList<T>` to retain the behaviour with any Property sub-type. It's sometimes quite helpful!

Comment: well that was easy...thanks! didn't know that you can actually extend with generics like that